# R data.frame: Efficient way to create counter for next change of value in column

Tags: r, dataframe

vector A:

```
a = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

vector B: (only used for initialization)

```
b = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Dataframe:

```
dft <- data.frame(a,b)
```

The following for-loop compares for each row "i" the value A[i] with A[i+1] in vector A.
If i+1 is different -> write "count"
else check i+2 and increment "count" ...

The idea is to know for each row, the number of rows until the value in A changes.

```
count = 0
```

% takes endless (for large set) but does its job

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dft)) {
    for(j in i+1:nrow(dft)-1) {
        j_value <- dft[j,"a"]
        i_value <- dft[i,"a"]
        if (!is.na(j_value) & !is.na(i_value)){
            tmp_value <- abs(i_value - j_value)
            if(tmp_value > 0) {
               dft[i,"b"] <- count
               count = 0
               break
            } else {
                count = count + 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results should be:

```
    b
 1: 5
 2: 4
 3: 3
 4: 2
 5: 1
 6: 1
 7: 2
 8: 1
 9: 3
10: 2
11: 1
12: 5
13: 4
14: 3
15: 2
16: 1
17: 0
```

Comment: I added the results I want to have to the question.

Comment: yes. outcome: [1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 1 1 2 3 4 5. I want to have 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1 0

Comment: The idea with rle(rev(dft$a)) seems to be the hint. it has the information I want to have in the wrong order (rev???). But the result is still not correct: with(rle(dft$a), sequence(lengths))
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 1

Comment: Maybe try `b = rle(a); unlist(mapply(":", b$lengths, 1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
b = rle(a)
unlist(mapply(":", b$lengths, 1))
# [1] 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1 1
```

Or in one line:

```
with(rle(a), unlist(Map(":", lengths, 1)))
```

---

Using "data.table", you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(a)[, b := .N:1, rleid(a)][]
#     a b
#  1: 0 5
#  2: 0 4
#  3: 0 3
#  4: 0 2
#  5: 0 1
#  6: 1 1
#  7: 0 2
#  8: 0 1
#  9: 1 3
# 10: 1 2
# 11: 1 1
# 12: 0 5
# 13: 0 4
# 14: 0 3
# 15: 0 2
# 16: 0 1
# 17: 1 1
```

Comment: This is nice. I didn't know about the `rle()` function.

Comment: Fantastically elegant. Bravo.

Comment: Cool: Thank you very much for your solutions. A

Comment: @rosscova, thanks. I've also posted a simplified "data.table" version.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using `data.table`. There's a bit of reverse ordering, and use of `shift` to compare values with subsequent values. It might be a little convoluted, but it seems to work.

```
library( data.table )
dft <- data.table(a)
dft[ , f := shift( a, 1L, fill = F, type = "lead" ) != a
     ][ .N:1, b := seq_len(.N), by = cumsum(f)
     ][ , f := NULL ]
dft

    a b
 1: 0 5
 2: 0 4
 3: 0 3
 4: 0 2
 5: 0 1
 6: 1 1
 7: 0 2
 8: 0 1
 9: 1 3
10: 1 2
11: 1 1
12: 0 5
13: 0 4
14: 0 3
15: 0 2
16: 0 1
17: 1 1
```

Comment: For the example it looks perfect. For my data set: Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dft, , `:=`(f, shift(a, 1L, fill = F, type = "lead") !=  :
  Supplied 17 items to be assigned to 3002627 items of column 'f' (recycled leaving remainder of 2 items). I' am checking it out now

Comment: Is the column called `a` in your data? It looks like the reference to `a` is finding your example dataset, which is 17 items long, which would only happen if `a` couldn't be found as a column in `dft`.

Comment: OKAy. I'll try it

Comment: THX :-) Now it works. My fault. Next time, I will use more expressive variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach with apply:

```r
# The data
a=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

# An index of the data
ind <- 1:length(a)

# The function to apply 

f <- function(x){ifelse(!is.na(which(a[x]!=a[x:length(a)])[1] - 1), # Check if we are in the last group before series ends
                        which(a[x]!=a[x:length(a)])[1] - 1, # if not return distance to nearest value change
                        ind[length(a)] - x + 1) # if we are return length of last block of values
  }

unlist(lapply(ind, f)) # Apply and unlist to vector
#>  [1] 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1 1
```

If you wanted you could reduce it to just the `which()` statement, in which case the last block of homogenous values would be assigned an NA. Depending on the context there are different ways you might want to treat the last block, as the number of repetitions until the value changes is censored (maybe you want to supply a string in the second term of the ifelse like '1+').

Comment: THX :-) It tried it with my larger data set and it works.